# Распаковка архива с заменой файлов

Tags: c#

Как распаковать архив с заменой файлов? 
Сейчас при распаковке архива полностью удаляю файлы и директорию, а уже потом на это место распаковываю файлы, но мне это не подходит.
Для распаковки использую ZipFile Class

Comment: Этот класс так не умеет. А почему не подходит вариант с ручным удалением?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение:

```
public static class ZipArchiveExtensions
{

    public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive archive, string destinationDirectoryName, bool overwrite)
    {
        if (!overwrite)
        {
            archive.ExtractToDirectory(destinationDirectoryName);
            return;
        }
        foreach (ZipArchiveEntry file in archive.Entries)
        {
            string completeFileName = Path.Combine(destinationDirectoryName, file.FullName);
            if (file.Name == "")
            {// Assuming Empty for Directory
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(completeFileName));
                continue;
            }
            file.ExtractToFile(completeFileName, true);
        }
    }


}
```

Пример использования:

```
ZipArchiveExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(ZipFile.OpenRead("./zip.zip"),"./ex",true);
```

Или

```
ZipArchiveExtensions.ExtractToDirectory(ZipFile.Open("./zip.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read, Encoding.GetEncoding(866)), "./ex", true);
```

Подробнее о `Encoding.GetEncoding` можно прочесть [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Решение нашел тут https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795197/forcefully-replacing-existing-files-during-extracting-file-using-system-io-compr

Comment: Единственная проблема: Если распаковывать файлы с русским именем, то кодировка имени собьется.

Comment: А как `ZipArchive` создаете? Там есть конструктор, принимающий кодировку

Comment: @АндрейNOP Для теста я просто создал архив и закинул туда файлы (Использую winrar)

Comment: А, вижу, используете `ZipFile.OpenRead`. Попробуйте так: `ZipFile.Open("./zip.zip", ZipArchiveMode.Read, new Encoding(1251))`

Comment: @АндрейNOP ругается на new Encoding(1251) "не удается создать экземпляр абстрактного класса"

Comment: Значит `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)`

Comment: @АндрейNOP windows-1251 (1251) не подходит, покапавшись понял что winrar юзает кодировку cp866 (866)

Comment: Ну и отлично, рад что получилось